# Reportlab, relative file link

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to create a relative file link to, specifically, an xlsx document in a pdf using report lab.
The same question was asked here [Relative File Linking in PDF (Reportlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331399/relative-file-linking-in-pdf-reportlab), and I am unable to comment.

EDIT: One person has answered, suggesting using file://, this does not relatively link however, but goes to the root file directory when clicked. (At least in chrome and OS X Preview, it is required to work in at least chrome)

Comment: "no-one answered". Well, there is an answer at that question, and you don't mention whether that works or not.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same answer for this question: [Relative File Linking in PDF (Reportlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331399/relative-file-linking-in-pdf-reportlab)

This is how I got relative links to files to work in reportlab:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

# Create a canvas and add a rectangle to it
c = canvas.Canvas("link_test.pdf")
c.translate(inch, 9 * inch)
c.rect(inch,inch,1*inch,1*inch, fill=1)

# example.xlsx is in the same directory as the pdf
c.linkURL(r'example.xlsx', (inch, inch, 2*inch, 2*inch), relative=1)
c.save()
```

I'm using Adobe Reader 11.0.10.32. When I click the rectangle I get a few warnings, but the file does open up after clicking "Allow" and "Yes".